# MVC - get a view with information from multiple tables

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

How do I create a view with information from multiple tables?

```
Select product.prodname, club.clubname from product left join club on product.clubid = club.clubid where club = "Miami Heat"
```

Newbie to MVC

Comment: How are you executing this query? Any code you have written so far to solve this? Any error you are facing?

Comment: are you using entity framework?

Comment: Yes I am using Entity Framework.

Comment: This is what I have currently to retrieve the data. How do I get that on my View? var prod = from prod1 in db.Product
                       from club1 in db.Club
                       where prod1.clubID == "Miami Heat"
                       select new { prod1.prodname, club1.clubname, prod1.id };

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we use `ViewModel` for that purpose in `mvc` where we create model according to view

e.g i have a view which needs `ProducName` and `ClubName` but they both are from different model, so i will create a view model

```
public class PageViewModel

public string ProducName { get; set; }
public string ClubName { get; set; }
```

so in view i will use `PageViewModel` as `model`

and in query

```
var data = from p in product 
           join c in club on p.clubid = c.clubid
           where c = "Miami Heat"
           select new PageViewModel
                                   {
                                    ProducName= p.prodname,
                                    ClubName= c.clubname
                                    }
```

Comment: Thanks. This was what I was looking for.